# symfony entity text input in form builder?

Tags: php, symfony

I've two entities in symfony :
first "User" entity that has a $addresses attribute that is a one to many relation to the second entity that named "UserAddresses" with fields:$id,$address(string).
i want to use symfony form builder to create registration page for my website and i want a text input for the user to add his address to his account in the registration page. when i use :

```
$builder->add('addresses', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'XXX\UserBundle\Entity\UserAddresses',
    'property' => 'address',
    'label' => 'label.address',
    'mapped' => false,
    'translation_domain' => 'labels'))
;
```

i see a input selectbox that shows the user addresses(that is already null)
in the registration page and user cannot add his address to it.
what should i do to replace this input element with an input type='text' element for the user to type his address

Comment: Here is a good answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381002/entitytype-as-an-input-field

Answer (score 2):

For `User` that could has many `UserAddresses`, use collection field type.

```
$builder->add('addresses', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AddressType(),
    ...
;
```

For further details, see the official symfony [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) to embed form collection and [collection field type reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

The difference with the Transformer and the collection type is that the transformer gives you only one textfield for an address and the collection type gives you a complete subform (think about address, postcode, city input fields) with the possibility to add extra addresses or delete an address.

Comment: The difference with the Transformer and the collection type is that the transformer gives you only one textfield for an address and the collection type gives you a complete subform (think about address, postcode, city input fields) with the possibility to add extra addresses or delete an address

Comment: @Frankbeen thanks for the complement. I add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) for transform `Address` to field before build form, and reverse transform text value to `Address` object in submit form