# EntityType as an input field?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form with a CollectionType field containing an email field (which is one of two fields of an entity) which I want to add and remove as I wish.

Here's the scenario:

I have three entities: `User`, `Cluster` and the relationship between both called `ClusterAdministrator`.

Entity `User` has plenty of all-around attributes (id, name, email, etc). Entity `Cluster` has a lot of attributes too, and one of them is `administrators`, which is an ArrayCollection. Entity `ClusterAdministrator` has 3 attributes: id, user and cluster.

My BD has around 50K users. If I add an CollectionType field of a UserType, and my UserType is a form with `user` as a normal EntityType, app will crash because it takes more than 30seconds to render such a huge select box. If I my UserType is a form with `user` as an EmailType, the form is well rendered (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8f7t.jpg)), but when I click save I get the error:

> Expected argument of type "App\AppBundle\Entity\User", "string" given

How do I make this work just by showing the email field?

Sorry guys, I'm quite newbie to Symfony. I'll appreciate all of your precious help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) available in `Symfony`. All that transformer does is, transform the string(User name or email) to relevant User object. Which should solve your problem.

For a better user experience, you can convert the text box to an `autocomplete` with the help of jQuery. I used it long back. I used [PUGXAutoCompleteBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle) to generate an autocomplete field and created a custom `Transformer` to feed the object to parent entity.

I can share some code snippet later by tomorrow if required.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeet. That's the correct approach I guess. I've been trying transformers these last few days, and I think I'm gettting there. Thanks a lot